# How do i resolve this error even if the required version is installed?

Tags: reactjs, docker, node-modules, action, yarnpkg

```
Run borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name e2caa166253314d58b81117c99f1cce31_ec68be --label 72882e --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_CMD -e INPUT_AUTH-TOKEN -e INPUT_REGISTRY-URL -e NPM_AUTH_TOKEN -e NPM_REGISTRY_URL -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/project001/project001":"/github/workspace" 72882e:2caa166253314d58b81117c99f1cce31  "install"
yarn install v1.17.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @testing-library/jest-dom > css > source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error jest-matcher-utils@28.1.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0". Got "10.16.3"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I receive the above error.  I have installed Node version 16.

Comment: This seems to run inside a docker image. Are your sure, your image has the correct node version installed?

Comment: node -v
v16.15.1

Comment: on your host or in your image?

Comment: image error is basically after the execution of an action in github repo

Comment: Still, the error happens within the image, because it seems, the image does not have a compatible version of node installed. It doesn't matter what version of node you have installed locally, what matters is the version of node inside the image. I'm not really familiar with github actions so I don't know how to select a fitting image. But that's the cause of your error

Comment: I have specified the node version there as well:                                               
        name: Install NodeJs
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

Comment: I don't know what specific version "node-version: 16"  resolves to. It might as well be 16.5 or anything below 16.10. Is there any possiblity to run something like `node -version` inside your image?